# Recursive sequence with a formula for a part of its criteria

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the next recursive sequence which firts terms are
$$2,\ \frac{3}{2},\ \frac{10}{7},\ \frac{17}{12},\ \frac{112}{89}$$
I need to express it has a general form for the $n$th element, I can't make it yet. It's composed by the terms:

$$a(1)=2^0+2^0$$
$$a(2)=\frac{(2^{-1}+2^{-1})\cdot 2^0}{(2^{-1}+2^{-1})+ 2^0}+2^0$$
$$a(3)=\frac{\left(\frac{(2^{-2}+2^{-2})\cdot 2^{-1}}{(2^{-2}+2^{-2})+ 2^{-1}}+2^0\right)\cdot2^0}{\left(\frac{(2^{-2}+2^{-2})\cdot 2^{-1}}{(2^{-2}+2^{-2})+ 2^{-1}}+2^0\right)+2^0}+2^0$$
$$a(4)=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\frac{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})\cdot 2^{-2}}{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})+ 2^{-2}}+2^{-1}\right)\cdot2^{-1}}{\left(\frac{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})\cdot 2^{-2}}{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})+ 2^{-2}}+2^{-1}\right)+2^{-1}}+2^{-1}\right)\cdot2^0}{\left(\frac{\left(\frac{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})\cdot 2^{-2}}{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})+ 2^{-2}}+2^{-1}\right)\cdot2^{-1}}{\left(\frac{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})\cdot 2^{-2}}{(2^{-3}+2^{-3})+ 2^{-2}}+2^{-1}\right)+2^{-1}}+2^{-1}\right)+2^0}+2^0$$

This sequence has this formula as part of it:
$$\frac{a\cdot b}{a+b}+b$$